# How to automatically build porfolio items in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, portfolio

I'm building a site using wordpress. I have already built a few and always felt that the portfolio building process that I use is extremely time consuming and rather stupid. All themes or plugins seem to work with the same method:

1. Make a portfolio post/page item.
2. Add title, featured image, content, category, etc.
3. Repeat

Since the structure for the items is always the same (i.e. the information from point ***2***), I thought there must be a way to have this information in a table for example, and have the plugin build all items using this information, rather than having to make them on a one on one basis. I'm sure something like this is already developed in some plugin or similar, but I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking into importing contents i.e. the portfolio items that are already present in other WP websites, then you can simply export them from that website and import it on the new site that you are building using the standard wordpress Importer feature.